# If A is diagonalizable and B is similar to A, then B is diagonalizable

Tags: linear-algebra

here is my proof, i need someone to check it for me.

$A = PDP^{-1}$
$B = PAP^{-1}$

Now i plug in A in B

$B = P(PDP^{-1})P^{-1}$

now i cancel out one of the $P$ and $P^{-1}$

$B = PDP^{-1}$

is this correct?

Comment: No that's not correct. We have that $A=PDP^{-1}$ and $B=QAQ^{-1}$, but who says that $P=Q$? Also, how do you cancel the $P$'s in your case? They are not next to each other and matrices usually don't commute. Even if they do, you would cancel all $P$'s in your case and find that $B=D$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- $A$ is diagonizable: $A=PDP^{-1}$.
- $B$ is similar to $A$: $B=QAQ^{-1}$.

Hence

$$B=Q(PDP^{-1})Q^{-1}=(QP)D(P^{-1}Q^{-1})=(QP)D(QP)^{-1}$$ which establishes the claim.

Answer (score 2):

The $P$ in both equation need not be the same

Let 
$$A = PDP^{-1}$$
$$B = QAQ^{-1}$$

and repeat your argument.

Useful property:

If $C$ and $D$ are invertible, then
$$(CD)^{-1}=D^{-1}C^{-1}$$

Answer (score 0):

So you are given that the matrix is similar to a matrix which is similar to a diagonal matrix (diagonalizable).  But similarity is a transitive property, as is easily checked:  $A=PBP^{-1}$ and $B=QCQ^{-1} \implies A=(PQ)C(PQ)^{-1}$. The result follows.